# Jar file names printed in logs

Tags: java, exception, logging, jar, message

I'm using some jars in my code. I've noticed that when logging, names of jar files are logged as well along with the package being used. Is this normal behavior? If I had to remove these names from logging, what should I do?

Comment: Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: Please add some code you had done.

Comment: how are you logging? what lib are you using for that?

Comment: I'm using xwork-core-2.3.32.

Comment: As an example, ifxjdbc3.5.jar. I'm using it for SQL related purposes. Whenever an exception occurs, it displays the jar file with complete package name and the line no that exception occurred on.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add an example log message, information what you're using for logging and how do you configurate it?